# Yesod persistent-postgresql rawSql queries with column-list wildcards producing syntax errors

Tags: postgresql, haskell, persistent, yesod

I'm using the persistent-postgresql library from Yesod, and I'd like to execute the following raw query:

```
SELECT * FROM utterance WHERE is_target IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1000
```

to select 1000 random utterances with a NULL is_target. However, persistent generates the following SQL when I run my code through `rawSql`:

```
SELECT * FROM utterance WHERE is_target IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1000"utterance"."id", "utterance"."message", "utterance"."is_target"
```

This generates an error in postgresql of `syntax error at or near ""utterance"" at character 77`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like its trying to expand your 'select *'

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: Well, why do you think it is called utterance?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by using the following query instead:

```
SELECT ?? FROM utterance WHERE is_target IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

rawSql doesn't work with column wildcards, because it enforces strong typing on returned data, so it's trying (and failing) to figure out where to put the column names. You need to explicitly list column names OR use some number of "??" placeholders in the statement and bind them at runtime like,

```
$ (Entity myType utterance, .... ) -> do ....
```

If you don't want strong typing, you probably also don't want to use Persistent; that's the entire reason it exists.

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you give a functional code example? I tried adding column names `SELECT id,message,is_target FROM utterance WHERE is_target IS NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1000`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I listed out all column names and now I am getting the same issue (Persistent appends some column names) without any wildcards in the query.